# Parse plain text data from a raw data with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a java code sample

```
response = Jsoup.connect(url1)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();
        response = Jsoup.connect(url1)
                .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
                .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                .data("__VIEWSTATE", loginPage.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").val())
                .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", loginPage.getElementById("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").val())
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$txtChonHK", "20192")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$btnChonHK", "Xem")
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                .timeout(0)
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
        Document doc = response.parse();

        System.out.println(doc.getElementsByClass("row-diemTK").html());
```

The result was:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esI13.png)
(i havent fix unicode error)
The problem is how can I extract plain text data only from td bar using jsoup?

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code.

Comment: @tomerpacific i have edit the question please take a look

Comment: seems like you have the plain-text (the bytes) but its not rendering in whatever editor you're using.